# Adding GPU to Docker on Rocky Linux platform

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-docker, rocky-os

I’m going to deploy an **“NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti”** graphics card to **docker containers**. According to the links below, I installed the driver for the graphic card and Cuda, as well as the toolkit for Docker **in Rocky Linux**.

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html

https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html

- The relevant drivers were installed according to the following path and also the nouveau module is not loaded and the nvidia module is loaded.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDYJQ.png)

But when a docker container is up and I run the nvidia-smi command on Rocky, it shows as follows that it did not find any processes:

```
Sun Feb  4 15:50:21 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.23.08              Driver Version: 545.23.08    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti     On  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8              N/A /  75W |      1MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

1. I started the respective container several times with the following parameters separately, but it didn’t make a difference.

   --pid=host --privileged --gpus 'all,capabilities=utility' --runtime=nvidia
2. The output of the strace nvidia-smi command is as follows:
   https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/uploads/short-url/2MTA1aRNltMyhrtvc7ERDjUs3Wc.txt

**my questions:**

1. I don’t know why the nvidia-smi command doesn’t show any processes and whether the graphics card is applied to the docker container or not? :(
2. My next question is that this nvidia-smi command should be executed in the Rocky system or in the container environment as follows:

   docker exec -it af868d81d6f4 nvidia-smi